# How to determine repeated click on each of a bunch of elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a bunch of dots and I need to do impossible repeated click on each of these dots.

I use array, where I put each element after first click on it. And then I compare clicked element with that array, but it doesn't work, clicks are counting with no limit.

```
$(function(){ 

  var clickedDots = new Array();
  var dotsClick = 0;

  $('.dot').on('click',function(e){

    if(!clickedDots.includes($(this))) {
      dotsClick++; /* this variable must increase only once on each element click */
      clickedDots.push($(this));
      console.log(dotsClick);
    }
    else {
      return;
    }
  });    
});
```

Comment: Please see my answer - posted just after you accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to add `$(this)` object, because every `.dot` DOM element is different from another. You can search in array, for instance, the position. For this, you should use `.index()` method.

```js
  var clickedDots = new Array();
var dotsClick = 0;
$('.dot').on('click',function(e){
    if(!clickedDots.includes($(this).index())) {
       dotsClick++; /* this variable must increase only once on each element click */
       clickedDots.push($(this).index());
       console.log(dotsClick);
    }
    else {
      return;
    }
});
```

```css
.dot{
   background-color:lightgrey;
   margin-top:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dot">.</div>
<div class="dot">.</div>
<div class="dot">.</div>
<div class="dot">.</div>
<div class="dot">.</div>
<div class="dot">.</div>
<div class="dot">.</div>
<div class="dot">.</div>
<div class="dot">.</div>
<div class="dot">.</div>
<div class="dot">.</div>
<div class="dot">.</div>
<div class="dot">.</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I find that it can be beneficial to add a `clicked` class to the `.dot` on click, and then evaluate whether or not this class already exists. Because you are using a class, you can also apply css easily to those items which have been clicked.

```js
$('.dot').on('click', function(event) {
  if (!$(this).hasClass("clicked")) {
    $(this).toggleClass("clicked", true);
    console.log($('.dot.clicked').length);
  }
});
```

```css
.dot {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.dot.clicked {
  background-color: red;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="dot">.</div>
<div class="dot">.</div>
<div class="dot">.</div>
<div class="dot">.</div>
<div class="dot">.</div>
<div class="dot">.</div>
<div class="dot">.</div>
<div class="dot">.</div>
<div class="dot">.</div>
<div class="dot">.</div>
<div class="dot">.</div>
<div class="dot">.</div>
<div class="dot">.</div>
```

@Zim84 suggested that I should use an attribute instead of a class, so if your interested in that approach, then see below:

```js
$('.dot').on('click', function(event) {
  if (!$(this).attr('clicked')) {
    $(this).attr('clicked',true);
    console.log($(".dot[clicked]").length);
  }
});
```

```css
.dot {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.dot[clicked] {
  background-color: red;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="dot">.</div>
<div class="dot">.</div>
<div class="dot">.</div>
<div class="dot">.</div>
<div class="dot">.</div>
<div class="dot">.</div>
<div class="dot">.</div>
<div class="dot">.</div>
<div class="dot">.</div>
<div class="dot">.</div>
<div class="dot">.</div>
<div class="dot">.</div>
<div class="dot">.</div>
```

Comment: Another option would be to work with the data- attributes instead of abusing a styling feature.

Comment: @Zim84 definitely could be, I will add a second snippet which shows how to do that as well.

Comment: @Zim84 amended.

Comment: Your solution is nice, but first answer is closer to my question.